# What scale is this (C# D# F F# G# A# B)?

Tags: scales

I have these notes:

C# D# F F# G# A# B

What scale is it?

Comment: You should correct your spelling.  The third note should be E#.  Scales are customarily written with each letter class only appearing once.  You have F and F#, but no E.

Comment: How come this has been closed, when there are several other very similar questions related still standing? Or do they need similarly closing, too? Just peruse the Related list.

Comment: @Tim if that does not fall in basic analysis question, what does?

Comment: There are many other very similar questions to the right (in Related) that are still remaining. Either they all go, or this is re-instated. Can't see why this in particuar is any different.

Comment: I agree with @Tim. We have answered many of this type of question. The "identifying scale" close restriction has to do with identifying the scale in a particular song.

Comment: Most of the related ones show more research, and explain why they did not find a standard that fits. Maybe some of the related should be closed also, or maybe this one should show a bit of effort about why the op didn't find the answer.

Comment: @Tom - there's the possibility that searching for a scale containing F and F# as well didn''t yield much, if anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# mixolydian.

The technically correct spelling is
C# D# E# F# G# A# B

It shares its key signature with F# major.

```
C# mixolydian:  C#   D#   E#  F# G# A# B
F# major:      (C#) (D#) (E#) F# G# A# B C# D# E#
```

Comment: It may be easier to see if you mentally lower everything by a half-step.  That gives CDEFGABb, which is clearly C mixoyldian (or F major, but Aaron is right that the start note makes it modal).

Answer (score 1):

As nuggethead states, that F needs to be E♯. That gives a key signature of 6 sharps - F♯ major. When *writing* music, it makes sense to dedicate one letter name to each line or space. Your way would necessitate loads of accidentals!

That would give the parent key, and key signature, as explained, of **F♯ major**. However, starting on C♯ and playing through to the next C♯ means it's not so much a scale, but a *mode* - of said F♯. And that mode is, as Aaron states, C♯ Mixolydian.